# Save only one string of multi-string command output

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, gnome-terminal

I've got a bash command to find the largest file in a sub-directory. I'd like to save the output to a variable to use it with other commands.

`bigile=$(find /path/to/directory -type f -exec du -Sh {} + | sort -rh | head -n 1)`

Unfortunately, this saves both the file size and the filepath.

```
echo $file
216K /path/to/directory/bigfile
```

If I pass the variable to commands take that a file as input, I see an error:

```
wc -lm $file
wc: cannot access '216K': No such file or directory
6333 217649 /home/path/to/directory/bigfile
```

Obviously, I get the output I need, but I don't want the error message. How can I save only the first string of the `find` command output?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following and let me know if this helps you.

```
bigile=$(find /path/to/directory -type f -exec du -Sh {} + | sort -rh | awk 'FNR==1{print $2}')
```

**Explanation:** Simply added `awk` after `sort` command and there `FNR==1` condition will make sure that very first line only is getting picked up then printing the 2nd field of that line too.

Answer (score 1):

You can also strip the leading file size from the expansion:

```
echo "${file#* }"
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this in bash (sed, awk, [substring removal](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100#Removing_part_of_a_string). Try this:

```
bigile="$(find /path/to/directory -type f -exec du -Sh {} + | sort -rh | head -n1 | cut -f2-)"
```

Added `cut -f2-` and quotes `"` to your command. Also works with filenames which contains spaces or tabs.